# Colander schemanode SelectWidget with "Select All" button

Tags: python, pyramid, colander, colanderalchemy

I just started working with the colander schemes; 
[with the select multiple select Widget](http://deformdemo.repoze.org/select_with_multiple/). How can I add a button "select all" that will select all options?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any automatic way to do that.  How I would do it is override the default template for that widget to add a button that would run some JavaScript that would select all the options.

BTW, that demo is pretty old and you may want to look at http://deform2demo.repoze.org/select_with_multiple/ which uses the latest version of deform.